# Database or File-Handling

Tags: android, database, windows, file-handling

To put a lot of searchable text in a software, what would be the best method, database or File-Handling system? Keeping in mind that the text is an Asian language with right-to-left orientation. Platform is Windows and Android.

Comment: Question is that what would be the best method, using database or a file handling system?

Comment: Use a database if you plan to do a lot of search-queries. You'll have to read text-files somehow and put them into memory in order to search for text, could be a problem especially for Android. A database should be way more efficient.

Comment: SqLite will be best but does it support Urdu Characters coz the text is in Urdu language or should i be using arabic characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Database** is the better option. It has structured format of all your stored datas. Database allows you to fire queries and search for a particular text you want. You can store and fetch data very easily and  with good performance speed. You can also delete any unwanted texts which is easy part.

Now incase of **File**, It is unstructured format kind of data. All your data gets stored below one another in line by line or. Fetching a particular word from bunch of whole paragraph is tedious job. Even You need to hold whole file's object all the time, which occupies more memory.